# Cannot use DB::select in public folder in laravel

Tags: laravel

TestModel.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;;

class TestModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'test';

    public static function index() {
        $configs = DB::select('select * from tests');
    }
}
```

This is my code. I have a file in /public folder name Test.php and want to use DB. But when i call the index() function in Test.php, it returns error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set
```

Test.php saved in public folder

```
use App\Http\Models\TestModel;

$configs = TestModel::index();
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: BTW what are u doing with test.php ?? Whats the need and how are u using test.php ?

Comment: I want to get the return value from TestModel.php (data from the database)

Comment: you are doing it wrong use controller and return the data there and dont use in the public folder.
 use combination of blade and controller

Comment: That's why my question is, is it possible to use the DB::select in public folder??

Comment: it isnt good method.i guess unless ur need cant suggest.

Comment: have u used controller ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using anything in public folder without calling index.php it will not initiate the database so to overcome this issue :

```
 /**
   * Using For Database Configuration
 */
 define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
 define('DB_USER', 'username');
 define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
 define('DB_PORT', '3306');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
 define('DB_NAME', 'db-name');

 $test = new TestModel;
 $test->addConnection([
     'driver' => DB_TYPE,
     'host' => DB_HOST,
     'port' => DB_PORT,
     'database' => DB_NAME,
     'username' => DB_USER,
     'password' => DB_PASSWORD,
     'charset' => 'utf8',
     'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
     'prefix' => '',
     'strict' => false,
     'engine' => null,
 ]);
 $test->setAsGlobal();
 $test->bootEloquent();
 $configs = $test->index();
```

Also, you have to replace one line in TestModel.php
replace use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;; with use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;

Now when you run this command this will be working for you.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'config' not found. There was an error. Or should I change the config into name of database?

Comment: How can I use Config? Thanks